Error while running make install: cannot change permissions of [directory]: No such file or directory
trying to install a package for Coq proof assistant, I have already had to jump through a couple hoops with it not playing nicely with Windows and am trying to install it on WSL. I get the following error running make install:
install: cannot change permissions of ‘/snap/coq-prover/34/coq-platform/lib/coq//user-contrib/LF/’: No such file or directory

(LF is the name of the package I'm trying to install.)
I've tried sudo make install, no dice.
I have Coq version 8.18 compiled with OCaml 4.14.1. I have WSL version 2.3.26 on Windows 10 running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

Can you be more specific about how you installed coq? It looks like you installed a snap version, instead of installing coq 8.18.0+dfsg-1build2 from the noble "universe" repository or Installation by compiling from sources using scripts / opam. AFAIK snaps are inherently based on a read-only filesystem so perhaps that method doesn't support installation of additional packages.

Is the cd directory set to the location your trying to makefile? It's probably looking in the home folder.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
